# Flutter: Custom drawer header items alignment issue

Tags: flutter

I have created a custom drawer header with a desired height. I have a close option, name and profile image on it.

**My Code:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double customHeaderHeight = 150.0;

    return Container(
      height: customHeaderHeight,
      child: DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff2799fa),
        ),
        child: Column(
            children:[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.clear,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Closes the drawer
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.account_circle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 60, // Set the color of the icon
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    Text(
                      fullName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Current Screenshot:

[image]

But I need the name and image on center and close option on right top like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}


class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
     
    
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(
    child: customappbar()
    ),
      body: Container(
        child: customappbar()
     )

    );
  }
}

class customappbar extends StatelessWidget {
  
   final double customHeaderHeight = 150.0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: customHeaderHeight,
        child:DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff2799fa),
        ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: Stack(
            children:[
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                  Icon(
                        Icons.account_circle, 
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 60, // Set the color of the icon
                      ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    Text(
                      'Micheal',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
              child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.clear,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Closes the drawer
                    },
                  ),)
     
            ]
        ),
        )),
        Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                title: Text("List item $index"));
          }),)
      ]
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please share the entire code inside `Widget build`?

Comment: you can change the customHeaderHeight depends upon design

Comment: I am getting a white screen when I am trying this. Can we do it without `AppBar` and `Scaffold`? Those things I have already in parent layout.

Comment: can u try the above answer